# Upload an Image from CKeditor with SonataMediaBundle and CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I managed to run the upload images via WYSIWYG CKEditor using SonataMediaBundle and CoopTilleulsCKEditorSonataMediaBundle.

The Upload works very well for ADMIN users, but does not work for users with the USER_ROLE,

Do you know how can I resolve that? thank you very much

Thank you !

config.yml

```
# SonataMediaBundle
sonata_media:
class:
    media:              Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
    gallery:            Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
    gallery_has_media:  Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
default_context: default
db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
contexts:
    default:  # the default context is mandatory
        download:
            strategy: sonata.media.security.connected_strategy
            mode: http
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
            - sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file

        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
    news:
        download:
            strategy: sonata.media.security.connected_strategy
            mode: http
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image

        formats:
            small: { width: 80 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 90}

cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
        create:     false
providers:
    image:
        service:    sonata.media.provider.image
        resizer:    sonata.media.resizer.simple # sonata.media.resizer.square
        filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.local
        cdn:        sonata.media.cdn.server
        generator:  sonata.media.generator.default
        thumbnail:  sonata.media.thumbnail.format
        allowed_extensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
        allowed_mime_types: ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png']

# FOSRestBundle
fos_rest:
view:
    formats:
        json: true

# CmfCreateBundle
cmf_create:
object_mapper_service_id: cmf_create.persistence.orm.object_mapper

# IvoryCKEditorBundle
ivory_ck_editor:
configs:
    user_config:
        toolbar: [ [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord']
        filebrowserUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
        filebrowserBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
        filebrowserImageBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
        # Display images by default when clicking the image dialog browse button
        filebrowserImageBrowseRouteParameters:
            provider: sonata.media.provider.image

        filebrowserUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
        filebrowserUploadRouteParameters:
            provider: sonata.media.provider.file
        # Upload file as image when sending a file from the image dialog
        filebrowserImageUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
        filebrowserImageUploadRouteParameters:
            provider: sonata.media.provider.image
            context: news # Optional, to upload in a custom contexta custom context

    admin_config:
        toolbar: full
        uiColor: "#000000"
        filebrowserBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
        filebrowserImageBrowseRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_browser
        # Display images by default when clicking the image dialog browse button
        filebrowserImageBrowseRouteParameters:
            provider: sonata.media.provider.image

        filebrowserUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
        filebrowserUploadRouteParameters:
            provider: sonata.media.provider.file
        # Upload file as image when sending a file from the image dialog
        filebrowserImageUploadRoute: admin_sonata_media_media_upload
        filebrowserImageUploadRouteParameters:
            provider: sonata.media.provider.image
            context: news # Optional, to upload in a custom contexta custom context
```